# how to generate multiple txt file based on months/year?

Tags: python

I have a large txt file (log file), where each entry starts with timestamp such as Sun, 17 Mar 2013 18:58:06

I want to split the file into multiple txt by mm/yy and and sorted

The general code I planned is below, but I do not know how to implement such. I know how to split a file by number of lines etc, but not by specified timestamp

```
import re  
f = open("log.txt", "r")
my_regex = re.compile('regex goes here')
body = []
for line in f:
    if my_regex.match(line):
        if body:
            write_one(body)
        body = []
    body.append(line)
f.close()
```

example of lines from txt

> ```
> 2Sun, 17 Mar 2013 18:58:06 Pro  IDS2.0 10E22E37-B2A1-4D55-BE20-84661D420196 nCWgKUtjalmYx053ykGeobwgWW V3
>
>
> 3Sun, 17 Mar 2013 19:17:33 <AwaitingDHKey c i FPdk 1:0 pt 0 Mrse> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 wo>
> HomeKit keychain state:HomeKit: mdat=2017-01-01 01:41:47 +0000,cdat=2017-01-01 01:41:47 +0000,acct=HEDF3,class=genp,svce=AirPort,labl=HEDF3
>
>
> 4Sun, 13 Apr 2014 19:10:26 values in decoded form...
> oak: <C: gen:'[ 21:10 5]' ak>
>       <PI@0x7fc01dc05d90: [name: Bourbon] [--SrbK-] [spid: zP8H/Rpy] [os: 15G31] [devid: 49645DA6] [serial: C17J9LGKDTY3] -
>
>
>
> 5Sun, 16 Feb 2014 18:59:41 tLastKVSKeyCleanup:
> ak|nCWgKUtjalmYx053ykGeobwgWW:sk1Kv+37Clci7VwR2IGa+DNVEA: DHMessage (0x02): 112
> ```

Comment: can you provide a few example lines from the txt file?

Comment: Are the lines in the text file already sorted by date and time?

Comment: added examples from txt... No they are not sorted

Comment: Does "large" mean too much to fit in RAM?

Comment: over 100k lines, ~500 mb in size

Comment: That would mean some of the lines are 5kB or more, correct?

Comment: I would assume so, as each segment varies in length but generally are within two to three lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex (such as [0-9]{4} ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d) ) but in the example posted the date is always in the beginning of the string. If that is the case, you could just use the position of the string to parse the date.

```
    import datetime 

    lines =[]
    lines.append("2Sun, 17 Mar 2013 18:58:06 Pro  IDS2.0 10E22E37-B2A1-4D55-BE20-84661D420196 nCWgKUtjalmYx053ykGeobwgWW V3")
    lines.append("3Sun, 17 Mar 2013 19:17:33 <AwaitingDHKey c i FPdk 1:0 pt 0 Mrse> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 wo> HomeKit keychain state:HomeKit: mdat=2017-01-01 01:41:47 +0000,cdat=2017-01-01 01:41:47 +0000,acct=HEDF3,class=genp,svce=AirPort,labl=HEDF3")
    lines.append("4Sun, 13 Apr 2014 19:10:26 values in decoded form... oak: <C: gen:'[ 21:10 5]' ak>       <PI@0x7fc01dc05d90: [name: Bourbon] [--SrbK-] [spid: zP8H/Rpy] [os: 15G31] [devid: 49645DA6] [serial: C17J9LGKDTY3] -")

    for l in lines:
        datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(l[6:26], '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
        print(datetime_object)
```

Which gives the correct output for the three examples you provided

```
2013-03-17 18:58:06
2013-03-17 19:17:33
2014-04-13 19:10:26
```

The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object has attributed such as `month()` and `year()` so you can use a simple equality to check whether two dates are in the same month and/or year.